# Notepad Tutorial: deleteDatabase() function

Tags: android, database, sqlite, notepad

I have a short question to the notepad tutorial on the android website. I wrote a simple function in the tutorial code to delete the whole database. It looks like this:

### DataHelper.java

```
public void deleteDatabase() {
    this.mDb.delete(DATABASE_NAME, null, null);
}
```

### Notepadv1.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, "Delete whole Database");
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {     
    case DELETE_ID:
        mDbHelper.deleteDatabase();      
        return true;
    }       
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But when I run the app and try to delete the database I will get this error in LogCat:

***sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg= no such table: data***

Can you help how to fix this problem. It seems that the function deleteDatabase can not reach the database.

Thank you very much.

Felix

---

Thank you for the posts. Now I updated the code:

### DataHelper.java

```
public boolean deleteDatabase(Context context) {
    return context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
}
```

### Notepadv1.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, "Delete whole Database");
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {     
    case DELETE_ID:
        mDbHelper.deleteDatabase(this);      
        return true;
    }       
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But now I have to restart the app that the database is deleted. I is not working while the app is running.

Answer (score 3):

The `delete` method you are using from a [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) object is to delete tables, not database.

Have a look at the `delete` method in the [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#deleteDatabase%28java.lang.String%29)

**Edit:**

Try calling from your activity directly:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {     
    case DELETE_ID:
        deleteDatabase(DATABASENAME);      
        return true;
    }       
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The way you are calling at the moment is to delete a database from a `SQLliteDatabase` object so I guess it won't drop the database until there is no more references to it.

Comment: oh thanks. I changed the delete methode: public boolean deleteDatabase(Context context) {
     return context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
    }. Now the database will really be deleted but not until I have not closed my app. If I close the app and start it new, the database is really deleted. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: In the Notepadv1.jva file the code look like this.         
            mDbHelper.deleteDatabase(this);

Comment: I dont see any reference to 'delete' in Notepadv1.java http://www.koders.com/java/fid662C390F21E9B60283DFA00EF51B5A75D3014B88.aspx?s=NOTES#L30

Comment: Thank's for the Edit. I tried it but also here the database is not deleted instantaneous. The screen is not updated. I have to restart the app to see that the database is deleted. I tried to call             deleteDatabase("data");  
            fillData(); 
            return true; But even this didn't help.

Comment: I did some tests and I can't figure it out :( . I ll think about it

Answer (score 0):

Per the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29), the delete method deletes rows from a table in the database. It doesn't delete the database itself.

I believe what you want instead is [Context.deleteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteDatabase%28java.lang.String%29)